# Evaluating a double integral by using $\int\arctan (1+\sin 2t)\ dt/(1+\sin 2t)$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:
$$
I:=\iint_D\frac{\mathrm dy\ \mathrm dx}{1+(x+y)^4}
$$
where $D := \{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\le1,x\ge0,y\ge0\}$.

I tried to evaluate it in the following way: first I rewrite it in terms of the polar coordinate:
$$
I = \iint \frac{r\ \mathrm dr\ \mathrm d\theta}{1+r^4(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^4} = \int_0^{\pi/2}\mathrm d\theta\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm d(r^2)}{1+(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^4(r^2)^2}.
$$
Then, I used the well-known technique to get
$$
I = \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\arctan (1+\sin 2\theta)}{1+\sin 2\theta}\mathrm d\theta.
$$

The problem is how to evaluate this.  I could get a simpler formula by substituting $1+\sin 2\theta$, but I would not proceed further.

I would be grateful if you give a clue (not necessarily a complete solution).

Comment: "Well known technique" I feel like such a square. What is this technique?

Comment: $\int dx/(1+a^2x^2) = \arctan (ax) / a$ and $(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^2=1+\sin2\theta$.

Comment: I am not sure if this can be evaluated in terms of known constants. If the original region were the upper half circle, $E=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\leq 1, y\geq 0\}$, rather than the quarter circle, then we can do something interesting.  In that case the integral is $$\iint_E \frac{dx dy}{1+(x+y)^4}=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\arctan(1+\sin(2\theta))}{1+\sin(2\theta)}d \theta=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{\arctan(U)}{U\sqrt{2U-U^{2}}}dU$$ which evaluates to $$\pi\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}}.$$

Comment: I think you're missing a factor: $r\,dr = \frac12 d(r^2)$.

Comment: The substitution $t=\tan\theta2$ leads to $d\theta=2\,dt/(1+t^2)$, $\cos\theta=(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$, $\sin\theta=2t/(1+t^2)$, and $\tan\theta=2t/(1-t^2)$.  Therefore $\arctan\left(\frac{2t}{1-t^2}\right) =\theta$.  And $\arctan\left(\frac{3t-t^3}{1-3t^2}\right)=3\theta/2$, etc.  So I'm asking myself what can be said about arctangents of other rational functions, since an arctangent of a rational function of $t$ is what this substitution leads to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $(\xi,\eta) = (\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}})$. In terms of $(\xi,\eta)$, the integral becomes:

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{2\xi }{1 + 4\xi^4}d\xi + \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1 \frac{2\sqrt{1-\xi^2} }{1+4\xi^4}d\xi$$

For the $1^{st}$ integral, let $u = 2\xi^2$, we have:

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{2\xi}{1 + 4\xi^4} d\xi = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{du}{1+u^2} = \frac{\pi}{8}$$

For the $2^{nd}$ integral, let $\cos\theta = \xi$ and then let $t = \tan\theta$, we have:

$$\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1 \frac{2\sqrt{1-\xi^2} d\xi}{1+4\xi^4} 
= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{2\sin(\theta)^2 d\theta}{1 + 4\cos(\theta)^4}
= \int_0^{1} \frac{2 \left(\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\right)\left(\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\right) }{1 + 4\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)^2}
= \int_0^1 \frac{2t^2 dt}{t^4+ 2t^2 + 5}
$$
Since
$$\frac{2t^2}{t^4 + 2t^2 + 5} = \frac{2t^2}{(t^2+1)^2+4}
=\frac{t^2}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{t^2+1-2i} - \frac{1}{t^2+1+2i}\right)
=\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{1-2i}{t^2+1-2i} - \frac{1+2i}{t^2+1+2i}\right)
$$
We can evaluate the $2^{nd}$ integral and get following ugly expression:

$$\frac{i}{2} \left( 
   \sqrt{1-2i} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2i}}\right)
 - \sqrt{1+2i} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2i}}\right)
\right)$$
Since $\sqrt{1-2i} = \frac{\varphi-i}{\sqrt{\varphi}}$ where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio,
the original integral can be expressed as:
$$\begin{align}&\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{i}{2\sqrt{\varphi}}\left(
  (\varphi - i)\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\varphi + i}{\sqrt{5\varphi}}\right)
- (\varphi + i)\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\varphi - i}{\sqrt{5\varphi}}\right)
\right)\\
= & \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\varphi}}\left(
\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{\varphi}^3)
-\varphi \tanh^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varphi}^3})
\right)
\end{align}$$
Numerically, the integral $\sim 0.3926990817+0.1021715030 = 0.4948705847$.

Comment: Thank you.  Is the substitution $t = \tan\theta$ useful when the integrand is a rational function of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$, in general?

Comment: I mean, $\cos^2$ and $\sin^2$.

Comment: @Pteromys Sometimes. It really depends on the integrand. However, it didn't hurt to keep this trick in your pocket.